# Clojurescript core-async: Async condition inside go

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a problem with ClojureScript Core-Async . This only happens in ClojureScript and not in Clojure.

I have the following code:

```
(defn cc [x]
  (go 
    (println "cc: " x)
    x))

(defn foo [x]
  (go
    (when (and (= :ok (<! (cc x)))
               (= :ok (<! (cc :ok))))
      (print "after and"))))

(foo 1)
(foo :ok)
```

When calling `(foo :ok)`, the result is as expected - the function `cc` is called twice, and the console shows `cc: :ok cc: :ok after and`.
But,  when running `(foo 1)`, the function `cc` is also run twice and the console shows `cc: 1 cc: :ok`. So, even though the first condition isn't fullfilled, the second one is still checked!

Comment: This sounds like a bug, not a question; I suggest you report a github issue for the project and report the version number.

Comment: @TimothyPratley you are right. This is a bug. I opened a Jira issue for it: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/ASYNC-158

Comment: Groovy! Thank you for reporting it.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a bug with the ClojureScript core.async library. I opened a [Jira issue](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/ASYNC-158) for this.

In the meantime I was able to work around this by using:

```
(go
  (when (= :ok (<! (cc x))
    (when (= :ok (<! (cc :ok)))
      (print "after and")))))
```